# Union Linq method not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<int> a = Enumerable.Range(5,5); // 5,6,7,8,9
IEnumerable<int> b = Enumerable(){2,3}; // 3

var c = a.Union(b)

c should be 2,3,5,6,7,8,9 but I only get 5,6,7,8,9
```

I just need the two of them joined.

Comment: Are you sure `Enumerable(){2,3}` is compilable?

Comment: If it would not be ok it wold not build. Range takes two parameters - start and range parameter. I bulids, has the numbers, but dous not concat. thats the issue.

Comment: method is working but you can't make it work.

Comment: It won't build as is (`Enumerable(){2,3}` isn't correct), while changing it to something that does, I get `Union` working fine. Can you check your question's example?

Comment: Look, That an example. I am sure it would also not build because I am missing ; in the last line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your code compilable

```
IEnumerable<int> a = Enumerable.Range(5,5); // 5,6,7,8,9
IEnumerable<int> b = Enumerable.Range(2,3); // 2,3,4

var c = a.Union(b).ToList();
```

and you will get `5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4`

Comment: That's od. Does not make any sense to me, why it should work. But damn it it does the trick. Really strange

Comment: @user853710 that's not correct. you want 2,3,5,6,7,8,9, (not including 4) this generates 5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4

Comment: The reason why it worked is because union is a deferred method. It isn't until the ToList method runs that you get the full results.

Comment: Don't use `ToList()` unless you actually need a list. Otherwise it's premature pessimisation; making things slower and more wasteful of memory before you've demonstrated that you need your code to be slower and more wasteful of memory here, and shouldn't concentrate any efforts to make your code slower and more wasteful of memory elsewhere.